# Attachment preview not working in Microsoft Teams: Bot framework v4

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, attachment

Teams Application with a bot and the permission of the file uploading enabled.

Can't see the **preview** of the attachment sent to this bot on Microsoft Teams even if the JSON response of the file upload confirms the upload success.

The attachment is visible on the browser via the browser link (if we are logged in with the team's web app).

The error message is:

> This item might not exist or is no longer available This item might
> have been deleted, expired or you might not have permission to view
> it. Contact the owner of this item for more information.

[image: preview]

Comment: Hi @Alberto Serra, could you please share he repro steps. are you uploading files from bot ? /  are you sending files to the bot?

Comment: Hi @Alberto Serra,are you still facing the issue, could you please share the repro steps.

Comment: Dear @Jagadeesh-MSFT now it is working! But I didn't edit my code. Do you know where was the issue?

Comment: Hi @Alberto Serra, it might be temporary issue. since it's also not reproduced from our.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got fixed though in this [bug](https://domoreexp.visualstudio.com/MSTeams/_workitems/edit/1744015)